# Redirect to new window in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, actionresult

I see this solution for webforms using response.redirect

http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2007/09/25/response-redirect-into-a-new-window-with-extension-methods.aspx

How do I convert that to a custom actionresult???